# jaxws multiple webservices single wsdl

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have created to Java objects and add the necessary @WebService annotations, etc. and I can view the wsdls for each on their separate urls.

I was hoping to combine the two services into a single wsdl file. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're the creator of these services, the easiest way is to merge Web services and you'll get one wsdl. Just put all methods in one service and you're done.

However, if you're just curious and ask generally, merging wsdls manually isn't trivial task. You need to pay attention to the namespaces, custom complex types and elements and method/operation names. There are some tools that supposedly do this automatically, you can try [this one](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl-merger-maven-plugin/).